# Using foreach on multidimensinal arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I tried to use a foreach loop on a multi-dimensional array, and found out that it didn't exactly worked out the way that I expected. Is there a foreach loop for multi-dimensional arrays, or another way to do this?

```
$array[0][0] = "a";
$array[0][1] = "b";
$array[0][2] = "c";

foreach($array as $a) {

    echo $a."<br>";

}
```

**Result:**

```
Nothing
```

**Needed Result:**

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k){echo $v . "<br>";});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
 foreach($array[0] as $key => $value){
   echo $value . "<br>":
  }
```

`$array` in this code you're accessing the key of 0,0,0 so it will not print it.

`$array[0]` in this code you're both accessing key 0,1,2 and the values a,b and c

Answer (score 1):

You need two loops.  One to loop the first array, and one to loop the inner one.

```
foreach($array as $key) {
   foreach($key as $val) {
       echo $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: It all depends on how many layers the multi-dimensional array has, right? So, three layers would need three loops, yes?

Comment: @frosty - yes.  If you don't know the number of layers, you could use a [recursive loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928993/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-multidimensional-array-without-knowing-its-dep).

Answer (score 1):

Try nesting another foreach...

```
$array[0][0] = "a";
$array[0][1] = "b";
$array[0][2] = "c";

foreach($array as $a) {
  foreach($a as $val){
    echo $val."<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `$a` is still an array. If you use `print_r()` you will see this:

```
foreach($array as $a) {

    print_r($a);

}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

To combat the nested array you have to run a second `foreach()` loop to get the values:

```
foreach($array as $a) {

    foreach($a as $value){ // loop through second array
        echo $value . "</ br>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

well since no one else has mentioned it:

```
<?php
$array[0][0] = "a";
$array[0][1] = "b";
$array[0][2] = "c";


echo implode('<br>',$array[0]);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/SC9PLI